# How to pass form value to controller using Ajax (Which type do i need in the controller part to accept sent data)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

I want to convert my form's data into an array using serializeArray() method and then I want to pass this to my controller's POST method as a parameter but I've tried *string, string[], object, object[]* and last but not least *Question and Question[]* (Question is my ViewModal that describes the shape of the Question) but only the *Question* works. But it doesn't work for more than one question in the view.

I did the **JSON.stringify($("ourForm").serializeArray())**, it does it's job but still I can't pass the stringified data into controller. (tried the String and String[] which I saw on this platform but they don't work.)

How can I do this job guys, I really need some help...

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateExam(String[] formdata) // 
    {
        var abc = formdata;
        return RedirectToAction("index");

    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
$("#submitForm").click(function () {
            var formdata = $("#ourForm").serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "/Teacher/Exam/CreateExam",
                traditional: true,
                data: formdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("BAŞARILI?");
                    // Do something here when it is finished
                }
            });
        });
```

ViewModal:

```
public class Questions
    {        
        public IList<Questions> questions { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="QUESTION GOES HERE")]
        public string question_string { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string C { get; set; }
        public string D { get; set; }
        public string E { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="CORRECT ANSWER")]
        public string correct_answer { get; set; }
    }
```

And my form: (I used partialview because I need the users to add as many questions they want and I got it working with some JS code)

```
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" id="ourForm">
            <div class="form-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success newQuest"><i class="fa-plus">  Yeni Soru Ekle</i></button>
                @Html.Partial("_QuestionLayout", Model)
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">SAVE THE EXAM</button>
        </form>
```

The ViewModal:

```
<div id="newForm">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 0px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <hr />

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"><i class="fa-plus">  SORUYU SİL</i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success newQuest pull-right"><i class="fa-plus">  YENİ SORU EKLE</i></button>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.question_string, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.question_string, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Soru buraya yazılacak.", style = "max-width:100%; min-width:100%" })

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.A, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.A, new { @class = "col-sm-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.B, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.B, new { @class = "col-sm-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.C, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.C, new { @class = "col-sm-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.D, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.D, new { @class = "col-sm-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.E, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.E, new { @class = "col-sm-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.correct_answer, new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.correct_answer, new { @class = "col-sm-1" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify(formdata) does the job.
BUT

the data must be like this on the AJAX block;

**data = { formdata = JSON.Stringify(formdata)}**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Content Type accordingly on your ajax call.

Comment: What type should I be using? Didn't work for 'json' or 'string', what else can it be? It has to be an array by the way.

Comment: For a complete breakdown of what content types to use for the type of data you want to pass, you can look at this site here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) - you can't pass an array as-is, perse.  You should convert it into a json object, then pass it via ajax, and server side decode back into an object.  set your content type to application/json

Comment: it didn't solve my problem but I solved it by sending data as **JSON.stringify(formdata)**

Comment: passing query parameters will work in ajax - I think you just need to set content type correctly because when your data doesn't pass in an ajax call - 99 times out of 100 it's because the content type is wrong...  But you did solve it with my other suggestion - converting to JSON - JSON.stringify() is how you do that :)

Comment: sorry, implementing this page took my 2 days and decoding is still a mystery on the controller side. Didn't see your suggestion over there :) Thanks. If you know how to, I'd really appreciate your help again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468651/how-to-reverse-json-stringify-from-controller-using-c-sharp