# How to Reverse JSON.Stringify from Controller using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am sending my formdata as **JSON.Stringify($("ourForm").serializeArray())** (I couldn't find any other way to send the form to the controller)

So how can I reverse this Stringify on the Controller side, using c# ?

The string comes like this (there are 2 question modules in the view):

> "[{\"name\":\"question_string\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"A\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"B\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"C\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"D\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"E\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"correct_answer\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"question_string\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"A\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"B\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"C\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"D\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"E\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"correct_answer\",\"value\":\"\"}]"

ViewModel:

```
public class Questions
{        
    [Display(Name ="QUESTION HERE")]
    public string question_string { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="CORRECT ANSWER")]
    public string correct_answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What how are you sending it as json content or form data? You should post what have you tried and why it's not working.

Comment: I added the string and the ViewModal. I haven't tried anything really. I need the reverse version of JSON.Stringify in C#. If you need more detail you can go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467236/how-to-pass-form-value-to-controller-using-ajax-which-type-do-i-need-in-the-con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).  It is easiest to create a `POCO` to deserialize to (although you can get tricky with deserializing using the `dynamic` type, if you wanted).

[[Example Here]](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TOWJ7)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Create model we can deserialize to
public class FormData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public FormData(string name, string val)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = val;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var formData = "[{\"name\":\"question_string\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"A\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"B\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"C\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"D\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"E\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"correct_answer\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"question_string\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"A\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"B\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"C\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"D\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"E\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"correct_answer\",\"value\":\"\"}]";

        var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FormData>>(formData);

        foreach (var datas in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datas.Name);
        }
    }
}

/* OUTPUT:
question_string
A
B
C
D
E
correct_answer
question_string
A
B
C
D
E
correct_answer
*/
```

Comment: My lord, thank you for the answer. It has been a pain to me for the last few days. Thanks so MUCHH!